# How to use integer variable in sql query

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlite

Using python 3 I am searching a database with the following query however, num_tests is a changing integer value calculated in my python code. where:

```
num_tests = randint(1, 100)
```

How can I search for the value  num_tests without updating it into the database, I want num_tests in the sql query to simply take the predetermined value of num_tests

```
test_db.execute('select count(testers) from test where' number_of_testers = num_tests')
```

Comment: Are you looking for string interpolation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *placeholders* in the sql statement, and then pass in a tuple that contains the specific values you're looking for:

```
test_db.execute('select count(testers) from test where number_of_testers = ?', (num_tests,))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
test_db.execute('select count(testers) from test where number_of_testers = ?', num_tests)
```